# RatingBar Android Studio - GoogleMaps API

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps

[[image: Hola quisiera agregar una calificacion a cada marcador es posible?]]

[image: Asi esta el layout del RatingBar]

Hola quisiera agregar una calificacion a cada marcador, la segunda imagen es el layout donde esta el RatingBar y la tercera quiero cambiar el valor de las estrellas pero me da nulo espero sus respuestas. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me imagino te refieres a NullPointerException, podrías agregar tu LogCat? ya que pudiera el problema estar en otro lugar.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/93d2acac518c29cb86e3101d3fda6055

Comment: Revisa si el layout que se carga con setContentView() contiene este ratingbar

Answer (score 0):

En base a tu mensaje de error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

indica que no existe un [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)  con id `ratingbar` en el layout que carga tu Activity.

Por esta razón marca NullPointerException.

El [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) con id `ratingbar` debe estar contenido en el layout que se carga a travez de `setContentView()`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        ...
```